# django dropdown item hyperlink not working when clicking

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I am building a Django app and everything is working except the link in a dropdown menu. I have followed everything that was necessary, but somehow the link does not make Django to render the page. Under `More` the link `About` should work, but it does not. I include the code and also I have deployed it temporarily for a production inspection:

http://azeribocorp.pythonanywhere.com/index

**html:**

```
{% load static %}
{% load staticfiles %}


{% block stylesheets %} 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/_topnavbar.css' %}">
{% endblock %}


<!--Top Navigation-->
<nav role="navigation" class="nav" id="topnav">
    <ul class="nav-items">
        <li class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'index' %}
                nav-item active
            {% else %}
                nav-item
            {% endif %}"> 
            <a href={% url 'index' %} class='nav-link'><span>Home</span></a>
        </li>
        <!--<li class="nav-item">
            <a href={% url 'index' %} class="nav-link" ><span>Home</span></a>
        </li>-->
        <li class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'track_containers' %}
                nav-item active
            {% else %}
                nav-item
            {% endif %}"> 
            <a href={% url 'track_containers' %} class='nav-link'><span>Track Containers</span></a>
        </li>
            <nav class="submenu">
                <ul class="submenu-items">
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Product #1</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Product #2</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Product #3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </li> 
        <li class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'search' %}
                nav-item active
            {% else %}
                nav-item
            {% endif %}"> 
            <a href={% url 'search' %} class='nav-link'><span>Search</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'report' %}
                nav-item active
            {% else %}
                nav-item
            {% endif %}"> 
            <a href={% url 'report' %} class='nav-link'><span>Report</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link"><span>More</span></a>
            <nav class="submenu">
                <ul class="submenu-items">
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href={% url 'about' %} class="submenu-link">About</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><hr class="submenu-seperator" /></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Support</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">FAQs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </li> 
        <!--
        <li class="{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'more' %}
                nav-item dropdown active
            {% else %}
                nav-item dropdown
            {% endif %}"> 
            <a href='#'><span>More</span></a>
            <nav class="submenu">
                <ul class="submenu-items">
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">About</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><hr class="submenu-seperator" /></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Support</a></li>
                    <li class="submenu-item"><a href="#" class="submenu-link">FAQs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </li> -->
    </ul>
</nav>

{% block js %}
    <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'js/_topnavbar.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock js %}
```

**css:**

```
body {
  margin: auto;
}

.topnavbar {
  background-color: rgba(20, 180, 255, 1);
  /*rgba(0,255,150,0.6); #3EDC99*/
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
}

.nav {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1)/*#3498db; */
}

.nav {
  width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Navigation */

.nav {
  font-family: Verdana, Georgia, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-items {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}


/* color of menu links
    span    {

        color:yellow;
    }
    */

.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.nav-item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.nav-link,
.nav-link:link,
.nav-link:visited,
.nav-link:active,
.submenu-link,
.submenu-link:link,
.submenu-link:visited,
.submenu-link:active {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.nav-link::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 10px);
  transform: translate(0, 10px);
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
}

.nav-link:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 5px);
  transform: translate(0, 5px);
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown .nav-link {
  padding-right: 15px;
  height: 17px;
  line-height: 17px;
}

.dropdown .nav-link::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  right: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
  /*small triangle showing drop down menu*/
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 1.46667;
  margin-top: -5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0) scale(.85);
  transform: translate(0, 0)scale(.85);
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-out, opacity 0.1s ease-out;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.submenu::after,
.submenu::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
}

.submenu::after {
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
}

.submenu::before {
  margin-left: -13px;
  border: 13px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
}

.submenu-items {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.submenu-item {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.submenu-link,
.submenu-link:link,
.submenu-link:visited,
.submenu-link:active {
  color: #3498db;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.submenu-link:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.submenu-seperator {
  height: 0;
  margin: 12px 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}

.show-submenu .submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 25px) scale(1);
  transform: translate(0, 25px) scale(1);
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.submenu-link {
  color: red;
}

.nav-link.is-active::before {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 5px);
  transform: translate(0, 5px);
}

.active{
    color:red;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

**js:**

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown .nav-link')).forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
});

function onClick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = this.parentNode;
    el.classList.contains('show-submenu') ? hideSubMenu(el) : showSubMenu(el);
}

function showSubMenu(el){
    el.classList.add('show-submenu');
    document.addEventListener('click', function onDocClick(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(el.contains(e.target)){
            return;
        }
        document.removeEventListener('click', onDocClick);
        hideSubMenu(el);
    });
}

function hideSubMenu(el){
    el.classList.remove('show-submenu');
}
```

**views.py:**

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'aztracker/__base.html')

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'aztracker/__base.html')

def report(request):
    return render(request, 'aztracker/__base.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'aztracker/search_form.html')
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [    
    url(r'^index', index, name='index'),
    url(r'^home', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^search', search, name='search'),
    url(r'^report', report, name='report'),
    url(r'^about', about, name='about'),
    url(r'^countries', list_all_countries, name='countries'),
    url(r'^track_containers', import_data, name='track_containers'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `js` file there has document `click` event. So when you click on `submenu` then the click event bubble to document and `onDocClick` function executed. To stop `click` event bubbling you have to add a new `click` event on `submenu` links with `event.stopPropagation()`.

Change your js code by this,

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown .nav-link')).forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);

    /** New event for submenu links **/
    el.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.submenu-link').forEach(function(sel){
        sel.addEventListener('click', function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
            hideSubMenu(el.parentNode);
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: should I add this separately, or I can include this as a function inside the current js file I have?

Comment: when I included it as a function, the drop down menu stopped working, but when I added the whole thing to the bottom of my js file, everything is working fine.

Comment: my code has first two line in your current js file, please check this you will understand where you will put the new code

Comment: I know almost nothing about js and that is why I am trying to figure out the best, but I was not sure so I asked you. I added the whole thing to the bottom of my file and it is working, so I guess it is fine?

Comment: Ok I understand your situation and yes it is fine to place the code in bottom of the script :)